# getColumnIndex() GIVING error in HSSFCell

Tags: java, excel, poi-hssf

Iam working on getting Column Index for excel Sheet using HSSFCell. This is code

```
                     if(cell.getCellType() == HSSFCell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC) 
                {
                    int index =  cell.getColumnIndex();

                    System.out.println(" The rowvalue is Numeric so Moving ahead");
                    String str = String.valueOf(cell.getNumericCellValue());
                    System.out.println(" String ---->"+str);

                    list1.add(str);

                }.
```

The Error exist on line getColoumnIndex. Iam added jakarta.poi.jar .
The error says method getColoumnIndex doesnot exist for HSSFCell. Kindly 7 rg

Comment: Is this the *only* error? - Clear project, rebuild. - Replace that line with a println of cell.getClass(). What is the output? Really 
`org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFCell`?

Comment: Have you made sure you have the latest Apache POI jars on your classpath? And only the latest, no old ones as well?

Comment: Tx, let me know the path to get the latest POI JAR,